# Size of $x^TAx$ in comparison to $|x|$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have that $A$ is positive definite, do I have a bound for $x^TAx$ in terms of $|x|$?

Comment: You need a bound on $\|x\|$ to have any chance of getting an answer. If $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, and $\|x\|=1$, then the biggest (resp., smallest) value $x^tAx$ takes on is the biggest (resp., smallest) eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean a bound for $x^TAx$ in terms of $|x|$.

Comment: Then please edit the title so it says that. Anyway, how can there be a bound in terms of $|x|$, if there's no restriction on $A$? Just multiply $A$ by 2, and you'll multiply the bound by 2. The only result I know is the one I quoted, for which you need $A$ symmetric.

Comment: In general, $|x^T A x| \le \sigma_1 \|x\|^2$, where $\sigma_1$ is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Comment: @copper.hat Since $A$ is positive definite, $\sigma_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$ (Rayleigh quotient).

Comment: @LinAlg: If $A$ is not symmetric, this need not be the case. Take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then the largest eigenvalue is $1$ but the largest singular value is ${1 \over 2} (3 + \sqrt{5}) > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lambda_{\min} (\mathrm A) \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 \leq \mathrm x^{\top }\mathrm A \mathrm x \leq \lambda_{\max} (\mathrm A) \| \mathrm x \|_2^2$$

Comment: Take $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $x = \begin{pmatrix}0.5 \\ 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$, then $x^TAx = 0.75$ while $\lambda_{\max} (\mathrm A) \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 = \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 = 0.25$. Indeed Rayleigh quotient requires $A$ to be complex Hermitian.

Comment: @LinAlg by a fairly common definition, positive definite implies symmetric, so that your matrix wouldn't qualify.  For the alternate definition, one should replace $A$ with $\frac 12 (A + A^T)$.